# Display divs beneath each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my divs display vertically (beneath each other) but I am having no luck, I really can't think of the problem, any help is appreciated.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atrjfpd6/)

I also tried this:

```
#div1 {
    float: right;
}
#div2 {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

with no luck

Comment: Divs are block level elements. They will be 100% width by default and will stack vertically. If that is what you need, you don't want to `float` them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had typos in my HTML and CSS